# Run code for every subset starting by filtering data with df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run some experiments with my Python code. The input of my code is based on a DataFrame. To filter my DataFrame I use `df.loc`. Before running my code I filter the DataFrame for the instance I want to run my code. I have the following list of instances:

```
instance = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

(These instances are also contained in a column in my DataFrame named `df[Instance]`). When I want to run my code for instance `'A'` only, I first filter my dataframe for instance `'A'`:

```py
df = df.loc[(df['Instance'] == 'A')]
```

When I want to run my code for instance `'B'`

```py
df = df.loc[(df['Instance'] == 'B')]
```

When I want to run my code for instance `'A'` and `'B'` I do the following:

```py
df = df.loc[(df['Instance'] == 'A') | (df['Instance'] == 'B')]
```

Now I want to run my code for all the subsets between `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'`. I can make subsets with the following function

```py
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))

subsets = list(powerset(instance))
```

Giving the following output

```
[('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]
```

Now I want to run my code for all the subsets starting with that it filters the DataFrame for the items in a subset. At the moment, I filter my DataFrames manually. What I want to achieve is that my code runs for every subset. Now I filter every subset by hand using df.loc. Has anyone a tip how to do this automatically?

Expecting:

Iterate through all the subsets.

Run code for A (subset 1)

```
df = df.loc[(df['Instance'] == 'A')]
```

Run code for B (subset 2)

```
df = df.loc[(df['Instance'] == 'C')]
```

Run code For C (subset 3)

```
df = df.loc[(df['Instance'] == 'B')]
```

Run code for D (subset 4)

```
df = df.loc[(df['Instance'] == 'D')]
```

Run code for A, B (subset 5)

```
df = df.loc[(df['Instance'] == 'A') | (df['Instance'] == 'B')]
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) which

> Invoke[s] function on values of Series.

It takes each value from the series, in your case `df["Instance"]` and passes it through a function. Your function only needs to check whether the instance is `in` the element of `subsets` you're currently working on:

```py
for subset in subsets:
    selected_rows = df["Instance"].apply(lambda i: i in subset)
    # do things with selected rows
```

Comment: With this function, I get back empty data frames. So I am trying to create something where I run my code for all subsets, starting by filtering the data frame and then running the rest of the code, this has to repeat until all subsets are run for. So currently I am manually filtering for each subset each time and then running the code for each subset. I think this question belongs better to the tag subproces

Comment: No, subprocess has nothing to do with this question. Can you modify your question to have a sample dataframe and your processing code? If you do `df = df...` then of course at some point your dataframe will be empty, because you're always overwriting it with the filtered one. The `selected_rows` in my answer only contains a boolean series, so you'd have to work with `df[selected_rows]`